# Identify and extract number from text files

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I am trying to extract data from a text file. The data in the file is somewhat random and has a numbers followed by a code.
(Example 1.25CROW, 4.25CRD, 10.25CR) I only want to extract the number associated with the #.##CR index. So if find 4.25CR
I need to parse only the 4.25 and add the totals of all these numbers. I have been able to identify the lines that contain the
`###.##CR` as shown below. What I am now trying to do is parse the number associated with CR and put each occurrence in a list
to add together, identify, etc. I have looked string.operands and re.match but I can't come up with a solution. Help would be most
 appreciated.

```
open("some.txt").read()
#txt ='CR'

count = 0
for line in open("some.txt"):

    if 'CRD' in line:
        pass
    elif 'CROW' in line:    
        pass
    elif 'CR' in line:
        print line
        count = count + 1
        print 
print "Total # Count " 
print count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep you are on the write track. You need to modify your last `elif` block as

```
elif 'CR' in line:
    print line
    count = count + 1
    value = float(line.split('CR')[0])
    listOfCRs.append(value)
```

Have a list before the `if` clause defined as

```
listOfCRs = []
```

Finally print the sum outside the loop as in

```
print sum(listOfCRs)
```

Few points

- Use `with open('some.txt') as f:` to open the file as it will explicitly `close` your file.

Comment: I forgot to thank all of you. All of you are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You could convert those to numbers by doing something like

```
float( line.replace( 'CR', '' ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open("some.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        # break line to words
        for word in line.strip().split()
            if word.endswith("CR"):
                try:
                    print "word %s-> %f" % (word, float(word[:-2]))
                except:
                    print "word %s has no number" % word
```